# Failed building a chart in meteor using dc-js, d3.js and crossfilter

Tags: javascript, d3.js, meteor, dc.js, crossfilter

I'm new to this forum, Meteor, and Dc.js, and i want to add some charts in a project i'm working at, so i found good tutorial for doing this [Making Dashboards with Dc.js](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/697043/Making-Dashboards-with-Dc-js-Part-2-Graphing), that i tried to adapt in meteor, i passed the first part without problems, but i face a problem in this 2nd part, because i have done everything but i can see no chart, there is no errors in the console, but nothing happen.

this the parts of my code:

chart1.html

```
<div id="chart-line-hitsperday"></div>
<div id="chart-ring-year"></div>
{{exemple1}}
```

chart1.js

```
    Template.chart1.helpers({
    'exemple1' : function(){

        hitslineChart  = dc.lineChart("#chart-line-hitsperday"); 

        function print_filter(filter){
            var f=eval(filter);
            if (typeof(f.length) != "undefined") {}else{}
            if (typeof(f.top) != "undefined") {f=f.top(Infinity);}else{}
            if (typeof(f.dimension) != "undefined") {f=f.dimension(function(d) { return "";}).top(Infinity);}else{}
            console.log(filter+"("+f.length+") = "+JSON.stringify(f).replace("[","[\n\t").replace(/}\,/g,"},\n\t").replace("]","\n]"));
        } 

        var data = [
        {date: "12/27/2012", http_404: 2, http_200: 190, http_302: 100},
        {date: "12/28/2012", http_404: 2, http_200: 10, http_302: 100},
        {date: "12/29/2012", http_404: 1, http_200: 300, http_302: 200},
        {date: "12/30/2012", http_404: 2, http_200: 90, http_302: 0},
        {date: "12/31/2012", http_404: 2, http_200: 90, http_302: 0},
        {date: "01/01/2013", http_404: 2, http_200: 90, http_302: 0},
        {date: "01/02/2013", http_404: 1, http_200: 10, http_302: 1},
        {date: "01/03/2013", http_404: 2, http_200: 90, http_302: 0},
        {date: "01/04/2013", http_404: 2, http_200: 90, http_302: 0},
        {date: "01/05/2013", http_404: 2, http_200: 90, http_302: 0},
        {date: "01/06/2013", http_404: 2, http_200: 200, http_302: 1},
        {date: "01/07/2013", http_404: 1, http_200: 200, http_302: 100}
        ];

        var ndx = crossfilter(data); 
        var parseDate = d3.time.format("%m/%d/%Y").parse;

        data.forEach(function(d) {
            d.date = parseDate(d.date);
            d.total= d.http_404+d.http_200+d.http_302;
        });
        print_filter("data");



        var dateDim = ndx.dimension(function(d) {return d.date;});
        var hits = dateDim.group().reduceSum(function(d) {return d.total;}); 
        //var hits = dateDim.group().reduceSum(dc.pluck('total')); 

        print_filter("dateDim");  
        dateDim.filterAll();

        print_filter("hits");  

        var minDate = dateDim.bottom(1)[0].date;
        var maxDate = dateDim.top(1)[0].date;


        hitslineChart
            .width(500).height(200)
            .dimension(dateDim)
            .group(hits)
            .x(d3.time.scale().domain([minDate,maxDate])); 

        dc.renderAll(); 


    }
});
```

and the main template that contains the first template:
pdv.html

```
    <template name="pdv">
           ...
      {{>chart1}}
    </template>
```

Please help me !!

Comment: I'm not meteor and others expert.
Try to use. **Template.myTemplate.onRendered**  I think helper method not correct time what yo want to do.

Comment: Thank you dear @lv0gun9, you reaaally helped me a lot and saved me a lot of time.